# Can anyone suggest why my code for postgresql walarchiveclean up is not working...I give two arguments as parameters but still it does not go forward

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This is the code for wal archive clean up in postgresql. I am passing archive path and age before when wal needs to be cleaned up. Its a wrapper scrip but somehow its not working. Whenever I pass arguments it throws first message for passing correct parameters even though I am  giving correct one.
   #!/bin/bash

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo -e "This script helps in cleaning up archived log files in postgres. Give the command with parameters in order\t
                sh walarchivecleanup.sh -p archivepath -a age (days) "
        echo "Usage : walarchivecleanup.sh -p archivepath -a age"
        echo -e "\t -p <value> -- Path to the archived WAL logs (e.g. /pg_data/pg_xlog/archive)"
        echo -e "\t -a <value> -- Age of archived logs to keep (days), anything older will be deleted"
        exit 1
else
        echo -e "Do Nothing"
fi

archivepath=$1
age=$2
##########################################################

while getopts "p:a" opt;
do
        case ${opt} in
        p)      archivepath=${OPTARG};;
        a)      age=${OPTARG};;
        \? )
        echo "Usage: sh walarchivecleanup.sh -p archivepath -a age (days) "
        ;;
   esac
done
###############################################################

if [[ -z $archivepath ]]; then echo "Error: Missing archivepath"; exit 1; fi
if [[ -z $age ]]; then echo "Error: Age (-a) must be given"; exit 1; fi

if ! [[ -d $archivepath ]]; then
        echo "Error: archivepath not found"; exit 1
else
        cmd_path=$archivepath
fi

if [[ -n $archivecleanup ]]; then
  if ! [[ -x $archivecleanup ]]; then
    echo "Error: Command $archivecleanup not found or no permission to execute"; exit 1;
  else
    cmd_command="$archivecleanup"
  fi
else
  if ! `which pg_archivecleanup 1>/dev/null`; then echo "Error: Command pg_archivecleanup not found"; exit 1; fi
  cmd_command="pg_archivecleanup"
fi

if [[ -n $age ]]; then
        cmd_file="$(find ${archivepath}/ -type f -mtime +${age} -printf "%C@ %f\n" |sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')"
else
        cmd_file="$archivefile"
fi

execute="$cmd_command $cmd_path $cmd_file"
`$execute`

exit $?

echo "Unknown Error - Should never reach this part"
exit 1
```

Comment: It looks like your script is checking for only two parameters, but you seems to be passing (and saying the user to pass) four.

Comment: `-p archivepath -a age` - four parameters: `-p`, `archivepath`, `-a` and `age`. Do not confuse parameters with options (`$#` variable contains the parameters count). BTW in many programs several options could be passed as single parameter like `-abc` which is a shorthand for `-a -b -c`.

Comment: @Poshi: thanks for the update

Comment: @Abelisto: got it...I guess I confused with number of parameters